# How to store an XSL attribute into a variable and use it inside as an attribute value inside a template

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

I'm creating a custom XSL for SharePoint and I want to make it reusable for other Data View Web Parts.  The XSL takes creates a tabbed view of a list using Bootstrap tabs. The tabs are generated by extracting the unique values in a column. I want to be able to define the column as a variable and then have the templates and for-each loops use this variable to generate the tabs and filter the list items. Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

XML is a SharePoint list, so:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
     <Rows>
        <Row attribute1="value1" attribute2="value3" attribute3="value3" />
        <Row attribute1="value2" attribute2="value3" attribute3="value4" />
        <Row attribute1="value3" attribute2="value3" attribute3="value5" />
    </Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="tabcategory" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row/@arribute2" />

    <xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="@attribute2" /></p>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="$tabcategory" /></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output currently is:

```
<p>value3</p>
<p></p>

<p>value3</p>
<p></p>

<p>value3</p>
<p></p>
```

The desired output is:

```
<p>value3</p>
<p>value3</p>

<p>value3</p>
<p>value3</p>

<p>value3</p>
<p>value3</p>
```

I need to be able to get the SharePoint row's attribute value by using a variable instead of the @attribute node. Right now it is returning an empty value.

Comment: May be you should correct the spelling to `attribute2` in the variable's xpath.

Comment: Oh the ignominy of a typo. Thanks for catching that. I think I may have oversimplified my example. I am still unable to get it to work entirely in the live SharePoint project. I will probably post a follow-up with more details if I can't get it to work.